# Android, how to pass view and viewgroup parameters

Tags: android, listview, view, android-arrayadapter, convertview

I want to change the background color of one of my views in my listview

`myListView.getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent).setBackgroundColor(0x00FFE303);`

I know what position is - this will be my index of the arrayadapter, but I don't know what view and viewgroup are. I have declared them above this line, but I don't know what to initialize them to

help?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem? Did u get any answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to be calling getView() manually like that. getView is called automatically by Android when a item in a listview is drawn to the screen. What would be most common to do, would be to extend an Adapter class (like ArrayAdapter) and @Override the getView() method.

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but can you elaborate on why that one-liner wouldn't work? And can you detail how I could pass the view/viewgroup parameters?